# Content Script Can't Call Functions. Firefox Extensions, manifest v2

Tags: javascript, browser, firefox-addon

I have a temporary extension I load into Firefox, it runs `main.js`, runs the function, but there is another function that it will not run. The function that doesn't run can only run if the page is refreshed, but not if it is a newly opened URL.

```js
let exampleArray = ['exampleItem1', 'exampleItem2'];
function foo(){
    let n = 0;
    exampleArray.forEach((element) => {
        /* code */
    });
    let msg = `example text: ${n}`;
    console.log(msg);
}
if (document.readyState === "complete"){
    foo();
} else {
    setTimeout(() => {
        foo();
    },5000);
}
// only main() is executed, unless the page is refreshed instead of loading a new URL
function main(){
    let exampleInterval = setInterval(()=>{
        /* more code goes here */
    },200);
}
main();
```

I have tried calling `foo()` another way, which did not work either

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete"){
    foo();
} else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        foo();
    });
}
```

This also does not work ^ 
Here is my manifest:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "example extension",
    "icons": {
        "16": "img.png",
        "48": "img.png",
        "128": "img.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "contextMenus"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js", "examplescript.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
            "js": ["main.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Only `main()` runs in the `main.js` script, and I can not run the other functions other than `main()` in the `main.js` script. Refreshing the page runs it, but if I click on another link and the page loads, it does not run, only the `main()` function. 
 
Edit: It seems like it is executing too soon, so I need a way to only start when everything has loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that worked. I want to write my answer here in case anyone else has this problem. 
 
I added these lines of code to my `background.js` file:

```js
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((id, change, tab) => {
    /* code goes here */
});
```

I then also edited my manifest for this to work:

```json
"permissions": ["activeTab", "contextMenus", "scripting", "https://www.example.com/*"]
```